# MVC 3 Razor - Form not posting back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I am using MVC 3 and Razor, attempting to post a form back to a controller from a telerik window (telerik.window.create) that loads a partial view. Im not sure how to post this so ill just post the code in order of execution and explain it as I go.

First an anchor is clicked, and onClick calls:

```
    function showScheduleWindow(action, configId) {
    var onCloseAjaxWindow = function () { var grid = $("#SubscriptionGrid").data("tGrid"); if (grid) { grid.rebind(); } };
    CreateAjaxWindow("Create Schedule", true, false, 420, 305, "/FiscalSchedule/" + action + "/" + configId, onCloseAjaxWindow);
}
```

And the CrateAjaxWindow method:

```
function CreateAjaxWindow(title, modal, rezible, width, height, url, fOnClose) {
    var lookupWindow = $.telerik.window.create({
        title: title,
        modal: modal,
        rezible: rezible,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        onClose: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            lookupWindow.data('tWindow').destroy();
            fOnClose();
        }
    });

    lookupWindow.data('tWindow').ajaxRequest(url);
    lookupWindow.data('tWindow').center().open();
}
```

Here is the partial view that is being loaded:

```
@model WTC.StatementAutomation.Web.Models.FiscalScheduleViewModel
@using WTC.StatementAutomation.Model
@using WTC.StatementAutomation.Web.Extensions           

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "FiscalSchedule", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FiscalScheduleConfigForm" }))
{
    <div id="FiscalScheduleConfigForm" class="stylized">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="padding">
                Using fiscal year end: @Model.FiscalYearEnd.ToString("MM/dd")
            </div>
            <div class="padding Period">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 120px;"></th>                   
                        <th>Effective Date</th>
                        <th>Next Run</th>
                        <th>Start From Previous</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HasMonthly)
                            <label>Monthly</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @{ var month = Model.GetForFiscalPeriod(FiscalPeriodStatementSchedule.FiscalPeriod.Monthly);}
                            @month.BaseSchedule.StartDate.ToString("MM/01/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @month.BaseSchedule.NextScheduleRun.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td class="previous">
                            @(month.HasRun ? Html.CheckBoxFor(m => month.BaseSchedule.StartFromPreviousCycle, new { @disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" }) : Html.CheckBoxFor(m => month.BaseSchedule.StartFromPreviousCycle))    
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                             @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HasQuarterly)  Quarterly
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @{ var quarter = Model.GetForFiscalPeriod(FiscalPeriodStatementSchedule.FiscalPeriod.Quarterly);}
                            @quarter.BaseSchedule.StartDate.ToString("MM/01/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @quarter.BaseSchedule.NextScheduleRun.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td class="previous">
                            @(quarter.HasRun ? Html.CheckBoxFor(m => quarter.BaseSchedule.StartFromPreviousCycle, new { @disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" }) : Html.CheckBoxFor(m => quarter.BaseSchedule.StartFromPreviousCycle))    
                        </td >
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                             @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HasAnnual) Annual
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @{ var annual = Model.GetForFiscalPeriod(FiscalPeriodStatementSchedule.FiscalPeriod.Annual);}
                            @annual.BaseSchedule.StartDate.ToString("MM/01/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @annual.BaseSchedule.NextScheduleRun.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td class="previous">

                            @(annual.HasRun ? Html.CheckBoxFor(m => annual.BaseSchedule.StartFromPreviousCycle, new { @disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" }) : Html.CheckBoxFor(m => annual.BaseSchedule.StartFromPreviousCycle))    
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                             @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HasSemiAnnual) Semi-annual
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @{ var semi = Model.GetForFiscalPeriod(FiscalPeriodStatementSchedule.FiscalPeriod.SemiAnnual);}
                            @semi.BaseSchedule.StartDate.ToString("MM/01/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @semi.BaseSchedule.NextScheduleRun.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td class="previous">

                            @(semi.HasRun ? Html.CheckBoxFor(m => semi.BaseSchedule.StartFromPreviousCycle, new { @disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" }) : Html.CheckBoxFor(m => semi.BaseSchedule.StartFromPreviousCycle))    

                        </td>
                    </tr>     
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="padding StartDay">
                <span>Run on day:</span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDay)
                <span>of every period.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="padding">
                <div style="float: left;">
                    @if (Model.ShowSuccessSave)
                    {
                        <div id="successSave" class="label">Changes saved succesfully</div>
                    }
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SubscriptionId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DeliveryConfigurationId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FiscalYearEnd)   
                </div>
                <a id="saveSchedule" class="btn" href="">Save</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('a#saveSchedule').click(function () {
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formValues, int subscriptionId, int deliveryConfigurationId, int startDay, DateTime fiscalYearEnd)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var selectedSchedules = GetCheckedSchedulesFromForm(formValues);
        var startFromPrevious = GetFromPreviouSelections(formValues);
        this.AddModelErrors(_fiscalScheduleService.AddUpdateSchedules(selectedSchedules, subscriptionId, deliveryConfigurationId, startDay, startFromPrevious));            
    }


    return new RenderJsonResult { Result = new { success = true, action = ModelState.IsValid ? "success" : "showErrors", 
                                  message = this.RenderPartialViewToString("_FiscalScheduleConfigForm", 
                                  BuildResultViewModel(deliveryConfigurationId, subscriptionId, fiscalYearEnd, ModelState.IsValid)) } };                        

}
```

As you can see I am using jQuery to post back to the controller, which I have done on several occasions in the applicaiton, this seems to work fine normally. But with this form, for some reason it is not posting back or stepping into the Create method at all. I am speculating that it has something to do with the parameters on the controller method. But I am fairly new to MVC (coming from ASP.NET world) so Im not really sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be greately appreciated!

Comment: It looks like your CreateAjaxWindow(title, modal, rezible, width, height, url, fOnClose) fnuction is not calling the url. Inside that function, url is not used. That's probably the issue.  Let me know if that's it and I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: Nice catch! lol Actually it just got cut off when I was copying and pasting. I updated my question.

Comment: LOL...sweet.  So any ideas yet on your issue?

Comment: No idea, the parameters on the method are all in form in hidden fields. There is some logic in the Create method to grab values from the rest of the form, but it doesnt seem to step into the controller method at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to post to the controller by modifying the textboxfor for the startDay:

Changed from:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDay)
```

To:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDay, new { id = "startDay" })
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're running on a virtual directory in IIS?  That url you're generating is likely the culprit.

Hit F12, check out the network tab (and enable tracing) and see what it's trying to request.

Instead of building the link through text, why not use `@Url.Action()`?  You could store this in  an attribute on the `a` tag (like in an attribute called `data-url`, for example) and then use that info to make your call. It's pretty easy to pull out the attribute with jQuery, something like this:

```
$('.your-link-class').click(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
   // proceed with awesomesauce
});
```

Would something like that work for you?

[shameless self plug] As far as the controller action signature goes, you might want to look into model binding if you can. One simple class and many of your headaches will go away.  You can read more [here](http://jameschambers.com/articles), read the parts on model binding. There are downloadable samples for different approaches.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Right now I am just running it inside Cassini, the built in IIS instance that VS 2010 launches. Which launches it as a standalone website (i.e. http://localhost:58830). I like your suggestion about using @Url.Action() with attributes, definitely cleaner! Thanks for that! I am reading through that site, thanks for that as well. I was actually finally able to get it to post to the controller, but I am a little confused as to why this made a difference and would appreicate any comments you all might have on that (see below)

Comment: I was able to get it to post to the controller by modifying the textboxfor for the startDay: Changed from: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDay) To: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDay, new { id = "startDay" }) But I have no idea why that fixed it. Any ideas? Seems as though it might be case sensitive, but the other form values are working with varied case.

Comment: Yes, the reason why that works is because model binding is case sensative. Your int startDay on your action isn't the same as StartDay, which is what MVC will generate for you with @Model.StartDay. Because you're using naked params instead of model binding to a class, the method signature is actually different and the binder can't sort out your params. That could be why the action wasn't invoked.  Hope that helps some!

Comment: Very much so. Although I have a question regarding your article on Model Binding. If I am understanding correctly the difference here is that you are defining the object in jQuery before it is sent to the controller rather than pulling data out of of the FormCollection in the controller, correct?

Comment: Also I noticed your article stated some caviots with error handling. I would love to share with you how I handle that. If you'll notice in my controller I have a method that calls AddModelErrors, this calls AddModelErrors on ModelState in the controller. I then return that to the view as a Json object with a collection of errors on the modelstate. Then using the success delegate on the $.ajax method I pass back an json collection, enumerate and display the errors. Obviously theres a little more to that, but I think you can get the jist of it. I can post more details in your blog if you like?

Comment: Sure, if you like, that'd be great. It *has* been some time since I wrote those articles and my approach has certainly changed. In those pages, I didn't have a form per se, which is why I was building the object in the jQuery -- both are valid approaches. My error handling has changed a fair bit, sounds similar to what you're doing.